# How to read numbers from a text file in multiple columns

Tags: bash, shell

```
names;x1;x2
jon, doe; 10;20
sam, smith;11;21
```

May I know how to calculate average where there are two different columns (x1,x2) in an input file for each name and I would like to get desired result as 10.5 and 20.5 using shell programming.

Comment: @mklement0 does it make sense now ? Pls let me know if u need more edits ?

Comment: Much better (with the [proper formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777)) - in the absence of explicit information, people will now (rightly) assume that the input has no empty lines; if you had done that to begin with, the debate in the comments on the answers below would not have ensued. The down-vote (which didn't come from me) presumably stems from the fact that you didn't demonstrate any effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: the problem itself was hard to solve until i knew what direction to head in ? I was looking in IFS direction but never thought of awk i hope i don't rcv anymore down-votes just because i am a beginner

Comment: Understood. Even if your attempts didn't succeed, it helps to state them to show that you tried. Even better would be to link to similar, existing questions whose answers don't _quite_ answer your question.

Comment: will try to demonstrate that next time i have a question in bash (i am sure i will). Appreciate your advice @mklement0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F";" 'NR>1{f2+=$2;f3+=$3;c++} END{print f2/c, f3/c}' file
10.5 20.5
```

Comment: This would provide wrong results with the example data provided by the OP that have lines with no data. @Tomas Ceruti's answer has considered this case.

Comment: I assumed it's a copy/paste artifact but you're right if the empty lines are part of the file it should be guarded.

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk -F";" 'NR>1 && NF {records++;x1+=$2;x2+=$3} END{ if(!records){print "No records found"} else{ print "x1="x1/records; print "x2="x2/records; }}' test.test
```

`x1 = 10.5
x2 = 20.5`

This skip the first line (`NR>1`), and skips blank lines (`NF`).
It also considers the case when no records are found